# Why am I getting an elisp error?

Tags: emacs, latex

I just installed yasnippets and addeded these snippets for latex https://github.com/madsdk/yasnippets-latex/

When I try to expand a snippet like "eq" I get the following:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{[yas] elisp error!}

\end{equation}
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t` and try again, then you'll at least get a stacktrace.

Comment: Also see `C-h` `v` `yas/good-grace` `RET`: "If non-nil, don't raise errors in inline elisp evaluation. An error string "[yas] error" is returned instead."

Comment: The debug-on-error didn't do anything, I guess because of the good-grace thing. But turning on reftex-mode fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it, so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug-on-error didn't do anything, I guess because of the good-grace thing. But turning on reftex-mode fixed the problem.